# Ignore everything except one directory in .gitignore

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

I have the following directory structure:

```
/app
/src
    /MyProject
        /FirstProject
            /Controller
                /file-1-1.php
                /file-1-2.php
                /file-1-3.php
            /Resources
                /view-1.html.twig
                /view-2.html.twig
        /SecondProject
            /Controller
                /file-2-1.php
                /file-2-2.php
                /file-2-3.php
            /Resources
                /view-3.html.twig
                /view-4.html.twig
/vendor
/web
```

I would like to **ignore all files** in my repository except files in `/src/MyProject/SecondProject/Resources`.
I have tried many ways but without success. GitHub application does not detect a directories that I want. Usually this application does not detect any file or detects all, so I am confused.

I tried:

```
# IGNORE:
app/
src/
vendor/
web/

# ALLOW:
  # my first attempt:
!src/MyProject/SecondProject/Resources/*
  # second attempt:
!src/MyProject/SecondProject/Resources/**/
  # third attempt:
!src/MyProject/SecondProject/Resources/**/*
```

*I haven't found a solution in an other questions!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `.gitignore` will actually work:

```
/app
/vendor
/web
/src/**/**
!src/**/
!/src/MyProject/SecondProject/Resources/**
```

[mipadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28804/mipadi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35329486/6309) refers to a mechanism introduced in git 2.7.0 and... reversed in 2.7.1!

The only rule left is:

[**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)

Hence the need for white-listing `src` sub-folders, before white-listing `Resources` content.

I tested the above with:

```
> git --version
git version 2.7.1.windows.1
```

Comment: I used this solution and it works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/3638163

Comment: @ZaquPL that is a solution that I wrote too (and that I reference here), but you don't need `!src/*`: `!/src/**/` is more precise. It white-lists only the folders.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. Perhaps I did something wrong, but I believe that your solution works so I marked this answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: @ZaquPL I fixed the answer. I missed the correct ignore rule for `src` folder: it is not `/src/` but `/src/**/**`.